# Executing sql script on a batch file with accent

Tags: mysql, batch-file, diacritics

I have some **accent problem** when I execute some sql script in a batch file ( the sql script create the database with tables and some inserts)

That's the batch file that execute the script file:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql" -u root -proot < dbase.sql;
```

That's the problem (he replace the accent) like that:

```
Ajout chÃ¨que entrant

Modifier date encaissement (ChÃ¨ques Entrants)
```

instead of that :

```
Ajout chèque entrant

Modifier date encaissement (Chèques Entrants)
```

That's what I do for insertions:

```
-- Insertion des Roles

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(1,'Ajout chèque entrant');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(2,'Chèques entrants à encaisser aujourd\'hui');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(3,'Chèques entrants encaissables');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(4,'Modifier date encaissement (Chèques Entrants)');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(5,'Rechercher un chèque entrant');



insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(6,'Ajout chèque sortant');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(7,'Chèques sortants à encaisser aujourd\'hui');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(8,'Chèques sortants encaissables');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(9,'Modifier date encaissement (Chèques Sortants)');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(10,'Rechercher un chèque sortant');


insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(11,'Ajout utilisateur');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(12,'Rechercher utilisateur');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(13,'Liste des utilisateurs');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(14,'Affecter/Retirer un rôle');

insert into dbcheques.role(idRole,LibelleRole) values(15,'Modifier mon profil');
```

Comment: The error is in `dbase.sql` almost for sure. I suspect you aren't running `set names...`.

Comment: no I don't think I have an error on the script . I don't see what do you means by set names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are seeing `Ã¨` instead of `è` I suppose that your `dbase.sql` file is encoded as UTF-8 but you don't tell MySQL about it. You'll possibly get the same result if you run your command directly rather than through a `.bat` file.

The most straightforward way to do so is by adding this on top of the `dbase.sql` file:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

To do so, you need to open `dbase.sql` in a text editor (I suppose you already have one since you are writing a batch script).

Alternatively, you can also call `mysql` with the [`--default-character-set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set) parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql" -u root -proot --default-character-set=utf8
```

Once you get this fixed, I suggest you read and enjoy these two links:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Thanks for your helpfull answer, but sorry where I put "SET NAMES utf8"?

Comment: @Majda See my edited answer. If it's still not clear enough, I respectfully suggest you consider hiring a developer.

Comment: Sorry I just see what you write . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Add `--default-character-set` option.

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql" --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -proot < dbase.sql;
```

Comment: how did you export the data? How do you check that the problem persists?

Comment: This should fix the issue.

Comment: yes it works fine but in the database the problem still persit ... but now it works fine thanks